# AccountManager getAuthToken SecurityException on API 21 (23+ working)

Tags: android, accountmanager

I'm trying to use `AccountManager.getAuthToken()` with my own authenticator (but in a different app with a different signature). I know that I need the permissions `GET_ACCOUNTS` and `USE_CREDENTIALS`. Those are added and working.

But I got a problem when calling `getAuthToken()` the first time via the `getAuthToken()`-variant which uses the `activity`-parameter to display a dialog where the user is asked to grant access to the authenticator (`GrantCredentialsPermissionActivity`).

This works fine on API 26+. The dialog is shown and after granting access I get a token.

But this does not work on API 21 - 26. Here, no dialog is shown and getting the `result` of `getAuthToken()` fails with `OperationCanceledException` and logcat shows:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Activity to be started with KEY_INTENT must share Authenticator's signatures

On API 24 the message has a little more detail:

> java.lang.SecurityException: KEY_INTENT resolved to an Activity (android.accounts.GrantCredentialsPermissionActivity) in a package (android) that does not share a signature with the supplying authenticator (my.package.name).

---

But when using the `getAuthToken()`-variant with the Boolean `notifyAuthFailure` instead of `activity` a notification is shown which triggers the "Access request"-dialog. And after granting, a token can be obtained.

---

So it seems a bit weird. The mentioned dialog is from the system and not my authenticator not the calling app. The authenticator isn't even called before the user grants access to it via this dialog.

I think this is a similar problem like [Android AccountManager's getAuthToken SecurityException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30103050/2170109) but there's no answer.

---

This is the dialog I'm talking about (grabbed from http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator):

[image]

Comment: Seems like this was a security feature and not a bug since KitKat (but  now changed in Oreo for the better). https://stackoverflow.com/q/20527528/2170109. But there's still no solution für API < 26

Comment: More testing reveals that even the `notifyAuthFailure`-notification is not showing up on API 24 and 25. So current state is that API 21-23 are showing the notification but not the activity, API 24-25 are not working at all and API 26+ is showing the activity as intended.

Comment: When asking for a `com.google`-account I'd expect that the system  shows `GrantCredentialsPermissionActivity` and therefor crashes with the same `SecurityException` but that's not the case. The user is presented with a **custom** "Access request"-dialog from the google-authenticator and not the system. How does google bypass `GrantCredentialsPermissionActivity` and shows it's own screen?